# Firefox uses remote name lookup before /etc/hosts

Tags: 20.04, firefox, dns, hosts

I have added the following line to my /etc/hosts file on Ubuntu:

```
192.168.0.104   www.tondering.dk www.xzutsfsdet.com
```

192.168.0.104 is an IP address on my LAN.

[www.tondering.dk](http://www.tondering.dk) is a server that exists on the internet.

[www.xzutsfsdet.com](http://www.xzutsfsdet.com) is a server that does not exist on the internet.

If I use lynx or Chrome to access [www.tondering.dk](http://www.tondering.dk) or [www.xzutsfsdet.com](http://www.xzutsfsdet.com), both of these requests are sent to 192.168.0.104, as I would expect.

But if I use Firefox, [www.xzutsfsdet.com](http://www.xzutsfsdet.com) is sent to 192.168.0.104, but [www.tondering.dk](http://www.tondering.dk) is sent to the external server (as if the /etc/hosts entry did not exist).

So it seems to me that Firefox only uses /etc/hosts if an external lookup fails, whereas other programs use /etc/hosts before performing an external lookup.

Is there any way to make Firefox behave as the other programs?

My operating system is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and my Firefox is version 78.0.2.

Comment: Do you have [DNS-over-HTTPS](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https) enabled in Firefox?

Comment: @muru Yes I do. I tried disabling it, and that appears to solve the problem! But I don't understand why using HTTPS would prevent the system from looking in /etc/hosts first.

Comment: That's the thing, isn't it? Firefox *isn't* using the system when it uses DNS-over-HTTPS. That's pretty much the whole point, I think: to bypass the system and local network configuration/restrictions in favour of a reliable DNS provider.

Comment: Thank you, @muru. If you rewrite you comment as an answer, I will acknowledge it as the answer to my question.

Comment: Traditionally DNS queries are sent unencrypted over port 53 over the internet which can expose private information like what sites you visit and when.  It also makes DNS queries subject to MITM attacks and blocking from unscrupulous ISPs and oppressive governments.  DoH in the browser solves these issues and instead sends DNS traffic encrypted over port 443 (with all the other SSL traffic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox has started enabling [DNS-over-HTTPS](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https#w_manually-enabling-and-disabling-dns-over-https) for users:

> DNS-over-HTTPS (DoH) [...] sends the domain name you typed to a
> DoH-compatible DNS server using an encrypted HTTPS connection instead
> of a plain text one. This prevents third-parties from seeing what
> websites you are trying to access.

This is a good thing, IMHO, but can cause things relying on local DNS configuration to break, such as intranet DNS and site blocking using `/etc/hosts` and so on. This is noted in the Firefox page:

> #### [Risks](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https#w_risks)
>
> - Some individuals and organizations rely on DNS to block malware, enable parental controls, or filter your browser’s access to websites.
>   When enabled, DoH bypasses your local DNS resolver and defeats these
>   special policies. When enabling DoH by default for users, Firefox
>   allows users (via settings) and organizations (via enterprise policies
>   and a canary domain lookup) to disable DoH when it interferes with a
>   preferred policy.

You can either disable it entirely:

> #### [Manually Enabling and disabling DNS-over-HTTPS](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https#w_manually-enabling-and-disabling-dns-over-https)
>
> You can enable or disable DoH in your Firefox connection settings:
>
> - Click the menu button Fx57Menu and select Preferences.
> - In the General panel, scroll down to Network Settings and click the Settings… button.
> - In the dialog box that opens, scroll down to Enable DNS over HTTPS.
>
>   On: Select the Enable DNS over HTTPS checkbox. Select a provider or set up a custom provider.
>
>   Off: Deselect the Enable DNS over HTTPS checkbox.
>
>   [image: toggle doh]
> - Click OK to save your changes and close the window.

Or exclude specific domains (and their subdomains):

> #### [Excluding specific domains](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https#w_excluding-specific-domains)
>
> You can configure exceptions so that Firefox uses your OS resolver
> instead of DOH:
>
> - Type `about:config` in the address bar and press Return.
> - A warning page may appear. Click **Accept the Risk and Continue** to continue to the `about:config` page.
> - Search for `network.trr.excluded-domains`.
> - Click the *Edit* button next to the preference.
> - Add domains, separated by commas, to the list and click on the checkmark to save the change.
>
>   **Note**: Do not remove any domains from the list.
>
> > About subdomains: Firefox will check all the domains you've listed in `network.trr.excluded-domains` and their subdomains. For instance,
> > if you enter `example.com`, Firefox will also exclude
> > `www.example.com`.

I would recommend using this option instead of disabling DoH altogether.